# Can a lambda that captures "this" to call a mutating member function be used to initialize a local thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I'm very new to concurrency, so the following code might be obviously troubling to the more experienced. The question is, does this implementation create any data races, or any other problems?

The background is that I have some number crunching work to do, and would like to use two threads. While one thread is computing the intermediate results which will be used later by the second, the other uses the previously generated intermediate results.

Details: in the call operator of class A, I used a lambda to initialize the first thread. The lambda captures the "this" pointer, in order to call a member function of A, which also happens to change the state of some data members of A. It also captures a functor, for generating intermediate results.

The second thread is constructed by another functor, which uses the intermediate results for producing the final results.

Both functors are passed in via non-const references because they modify their own respective data members.

A 2nd question is, can I move the definitions of the lambda functions out of the for loop, and use them to construct the two threads (then join) inside the loop.

```
class A{
private:

    data_type m_data;

    void m_fun(){
        // mutate m_data
    }

public:

    A() = default;

    // functor_1 and 2 are different types
    void operator()(functor_1&, functor_2&);
};

void A::operator()(functor_1& f_1, functor_2& f_2){

    T intermediate_copy_1, intermediate_copy_2; // both are big, matrix like structures

    // initial content of intermediate_copy_1 generated by functor_2
    // then,

    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i){
        auto foo = [this, &f_2, &intermediate_copy_2]{
            m_fun();
            f_2(intermediate_copy_2);
        };

        auto bar = [&f_1, &intermediate_copy_1]{
            f_1(intermediate_copy_1);
        };

        std::thread t_foo(foo);
        std::thread t_bar(bar);

        t_foo.join();
        t_bar.join();

        // after both threads finished, pass copy_2 to copy_1 for use in next round.
        // copying is relatively cheap
        intermediate_copy_1 = intermediate_copy_2;
    }
    // a little more work
}
```

Comment: Having a full but minimal working program that compiles would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code you've shown; no obvious data races. And yes, you can hoist the definitions of `foo` and `bar` out of the loop.

Comment: There's no reason to spawn *two* threads and wait for them both to finish when you could run one of the functions on the current thread.

Comment: @Casey. But doesn't joining another thread blocks temporarily the current thread, while if I have two other concurrent threads, they don't block each other if there is no data race?

Comment: @CloudyTrees Yes, joining blocks the current thread. That's why you want to join *after* the computation completes. `std::thread t_foo(foo); bar(); t_foo.join();` is semantically identical to what you have now but avoids half of the thread creation overhead.